# 301 redirect for a url via web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-301, redirect

I want to redirect a url to be be redirected to another url preserving querystring:

I want to redirect this url:

```
http://my.website.com/utilities/myservice.svc/item?longquerystring
```

to

```
http://my.website.com/utilities/myservice.svc/items?longquerystring
```

I have written the following code in my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Test" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="http://my.website.com/utilities/myservice.svc/item(.*)" />
                  <action type="Redirect" url="http://my.website.com/utilities/myservice.svc/items" 

appendQueryString="true" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

The above code is not working. Can you help me writing the correct rule there?

Comment: Define "*not working*"?

Comment: check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx

Comment: "Not working" I mean to say the 301 redirect is not working there. No redirection is applied.

Comment: Have you tried removing the scheme (HTTP) and host (my.website.com) from the match URL?